# Change title of navigation bar when tab controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

First here is the layout

[image: main.storyboad]

I am trying to change the title of the navigation bar so on screen one (top - right) it says Now Playing while on the one directly below that it should say About.

However I am having an small issue doing this. You see on the tabview controller I can set it. However on the first and second views (the ones on far right) I am not able to set it.

I am wondering how I fix this?

I am using Swift + storyboards.

Comment: storyboard picture is not clear.

Comment: @SGDev how so? On the two screens on the right I need there to be a title for each of them

Comment: by using code you can set navigation title `self.navigationController?.title = "abcd" `. or you can set the Title property of ViewController from stroyboard.

Comment: @SGDev that worked - Sorry NOOB alert

Comment: @SGDev is this what I should also be doing for background music? As I currently have all the code in that (first view - top right) and I have noticed it has stopped playing when I switch views,.

Comment: put your music playing code inside some common class and then control from difference VC.

Comment: @SGDev - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014737/should-i-be-using-avkit-player-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using code you can set navigation title

```
self.navigationController?.title = "abcd"
```

Or you can set the `Title` property of `ViewController` from `stroyboard`.